# NodeJS writing out large file using pipes

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm new to nodejs...doing some serverside file conversion.

I'm using pipes to read data from a stream, convert, then write the converted data into a file.  Works great for small files.  But for large files, it suffers from two issues:

1. The data isn't written to the file gradually.
2. It is using a lot of memory, so every consecutive 100,000 lines
   takes longer to process.

I think it has something to do with calling process.nextTick.  I can't figure out how to put the whole thing together.

I have something like:

```
readableFileStream.pipe(through(convert)).pipe(fileWritableStream);

function convert(buf) {
   //do something to buf
   this.queue(convertedBuf);
}
```

I wanted to something like:

```
var threashold = 100000;
var cnt = 0;
function convert(buf) {
   cnt++;
   if (cnt > threashold && cnt % threashold == 0) {
        process.nextTick(doSomething);
   }
   //do something to buf
   this.queue(convertedBuf);
}
```

Clearly that doesn't work, nextTick doesn't take a parameter.  How should one deal with a situation like this?

Comment: Why are you counting the number of times your `convert` function is called?  It won't be called once per line.  Streams typically operate on streams of bytes - they don't even care whether its ASCII, so newlines don't mean anything special.  Also, `nextTick` is almost certainly not the answer here.  It sounds like you're suffering from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - please try to describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @AaronDufour - I've already explained the problem, and its symptoms.  My approach was try to figure out a way to flush to the file more frequently...instead of waiting till the conversion is done.  That's why I was using a threashold.  My stream is in objectMode so buf is just one object.

Comment: See, I had no idea you were trying to flush the file.  That's a step in the right direction.  However, `nextTick` _does_ take a parameter, so your question still doesn't make a ton of sense to me.  Also, a `WriteStream` gives you no way to forcibly flush it since it does this automatically, so I'm not sure what your plan is there.  You might be describing a bug in the `fs` module?

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks for the follow up.  I'm new to node. All I want to do is write a lot of data to a file.  How should I do that using pipes?  Let's not hang up on the nextTick stuff.  I just put it there as an approach I was trying.  How would you write lots of data into a file using pipes?  Let's start with this: readableFileStream.pipe(through(convert)).pipe(fileWritableStream);  How do you do this for large amount of data...how do you get the fileWritableStream to output its buffer at regular intervals?

Comment: What you have should work fine for large amounts of data as long as your `convert` function works well.  What  if you just pipe the readStream into the writeStream?  It has no problem flushing itself on my system; I just piped a random stream into a fs writeStream and it successfully wrote 4GB, which is far more than node can hold in memory.